# Unable to select a GLX visual

Tags: python, opengl, x11, glx

I have written an opengl program in python but have hit issues with glxChooseVisual.

Basically it fails to find a matching visual if I use the attributes below every thing is fine

```
    self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_RGBA, 1)
    self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_RED_SIZE, 8)
    self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8)
    self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8)
```

how ever if I add any of the following for example it fails to match a visual and just segfaults due to glxchoosevisual returning none.

GLX_ALPHA_SIZE
GLX_DEPTH_SIZE
GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER
GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE

The machine has an nvidia card and also an onboard graphics card, i am using the nvidia one and games and app like blender work fine. I have read some where that glxchoosevisual may be using the wrong libgl.so file but i do not knwo how to check or how to further debug why my code can not match a visual.

running glxinfo returns the following, can anyone advise on how to proceed in debugging this ?

```
311 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x105 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x106 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x107 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x108 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x109 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x10f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x110 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x111 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x112 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x113 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x114 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x115 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x116 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x117 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x118 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x119 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x11d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x11e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x11f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x120 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x121 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x122 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x123 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x124 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x125 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x126 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x127 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x128 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x129 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x12a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x12b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x12c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x12d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x12e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x12f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x130 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x131 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x132 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x133 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x134 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x135 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x136 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x137 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x138 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x139 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x13a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x13b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x13c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x13d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x13e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x13f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x140 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x141 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x142 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x143 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x144 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x145 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x146 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x147 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x148 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x149 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x14a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x14b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x14c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x14d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x14e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x14f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x150 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x151 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x152 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x153 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x154 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x155 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x156 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x157 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x158 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x159 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x15a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x15b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x15c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x15d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x15e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x15f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x160 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x161 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x162 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x163 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x164 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x165 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x166 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x167 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x168 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x169 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x16a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x16b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x16c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x16d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x16e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x16f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x170 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x171 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x172 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x173 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x174 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x175 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x176 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x177 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x178 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x179 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x17a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x17b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x17c 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x17d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x17e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x17f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x180 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x181 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x182 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x183 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x184 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x185 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x186 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x187 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x188 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x189 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x18a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x18b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x18c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x18d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x18e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x18f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x190 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x191 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x192 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x193 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x194 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x195 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x196 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x197 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x198 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x199 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x19a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x19b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x19c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x19d 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x19e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x19f 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a0 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a1 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a2 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a3 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a5 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a7 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a8 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1a9 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1aa 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1ab 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1ac 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1ad 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1ae 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1af 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1b0 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1b1 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1b2 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1b3 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1b4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1b5 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1b6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x1b7 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1b8 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x1b9 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1ba 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1bb 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1bc 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1bd 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1be 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1bf 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1c0 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1c1 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c2 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c3 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c5 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c7 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c8 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1c9 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1ca 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1cb 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1cc 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1cd 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1ce 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1cf 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1d0 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1d1 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1d2 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1d3 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1d4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1d5 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1d6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1d7 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1d8 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1d9 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1da 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1db 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1dc 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  8 1 Ncon
0x1dd 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1de 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1df 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1e0 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 16 1 Ncon
0x1e1 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e2 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e3 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  0 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e5 32 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e7 32 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e8 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  4 24  8 16 16 16 16 32 1 Ncon
0x1e9  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1ea  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1eb  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1ec  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1ed  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1ee  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1ef  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f0  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f1  0 sg  0   0  0 r  . .   0  0  0  0 .  .  4 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f2  0 sg  0   0  0 r  . .   0  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f3  0 sg  0   0  0 r  . .   0  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f4  0 sg  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f5  0 sg  0  32  0    . .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f6  0 sg  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f7  0 sg  0  32  0    y .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f8  0 sg  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1f9  0 sg  0  32  0    . .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1fa  0 sg  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1fb  0 sg  0  32  0    y .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1fc  0 sg  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1fd  0 sg  0  64  0    . .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1fe  0 sg  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x1ff  0 sg  0  64  0    y .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x200  0 sg  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x201  0 sg  0 128  0    . .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x202  0 sg  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x203  0 sg  0 128  0    y .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x204  0 sg  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x205  0 sg  0  32  0    . .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x206  0 sg  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x207  0 sg  0  32  0    y .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x208  0 sg  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x209  0 sg  0  32  0    . .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x20a  0 sg  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x20b  0 sg  0  32  0    y .  16 16  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x20c  0 sg  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x20d  0 sg  0  32  0    . .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x20e  0 sg  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x20f  0 sg  0  32  0    y .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x210  0 sg  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x211  0 sg  0  32  0    . .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x212  0 sg  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x213  0 sg  0  32  0    y .  32  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x214  0 sg  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x215  0 sg  0  64  0    . .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x216  0 sg  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x217  0 sg  0  64  0    y .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x218  0 sg  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x219  0 sg  0  64  0    . .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x21a  0 sg  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x21b  0 sg  0  64  0    y .  16 16 16 16 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x21c  0 sg  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x21d  0 sg  0 128  0    . .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x21e  0 sg  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x21f  0 sg  0 128  0    y .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x220  0 sg  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x221  0 sg  0 128  0    . .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x222  0 sg  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x223  0 sg  0 128  0    y .  32 32 32 32 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x224  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x225  0 sg  0  16  0    . .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x226  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x227  0 sg  0  16  0    y .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x228  0 sg  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x229  0 sg  0  64  0    . .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x22a  0 sg  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x22b  0 sg  0  64  0    y .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x22c  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x22d  0 sg  0  16  0    . .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x22e  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x22f  0 sg  0  16  0    y .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x230  0 sg  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x231  0 sg  0  16  0    . .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x232  0 sg  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x233  0 sg  0  16  0    y .  16  0  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x234  0 sg  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x235  0 sg  0  64  0    . .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x236  0 sg  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x237  0 sg  0  64  0    y .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x238  0 sg  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x239  0 sg  0  64  0    . .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x23a  0 sg  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x23b  0 sg  0  64  0    y .  32 32  0  0 f  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to select a visual with a nonzero alpha component. That is… tricky. The problem here is, that an alpha channel on a regular window is often not exposed through a regular visual, but a FBConfig which has been introduced only with the XRender extension (note how `glxinfo` is reporting supported `GLXFBConfigs` instead of `GLX Visuals` for formats that have an alpha channel. So you must use `glXChooseFBConfig` to select a GLXFBConfig. You can then use `glXGetVisualFromFBConfig` to get the visual matching that FBConfig. Also you pass that FBConfig to either `glXCreateContextAttribsARB` or `glXCreateNewContext` depending on what you use for creating the context.

If your goal is implementing a OpenGL context that can be used for transparent rendering in a composited X11 environment there are a few additional hoops to jump. Namely you have to test which FBConfig corresponds to a XRender picture format that has an alpha_mask.

I showcased all this in my [`x11argb_opengl`](https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c) sample code.

Comment: Thanks that information looks great, I will have a play around and see if that helps and try and translate your example into python.

Comment: Well i am still having issues, seems glxGetVisualFromFBConfig always fails but I will post another question with some code at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986657/why-does-glxgetvisualfromfbconfig-always-fail-to-find-a-valid-visual-from-my-fbc